# creating Ruby on rails application with existing source giving an error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, netbeans

i'm trying to create a new ROR project in netbeans from the existing source that is saved on my network drive but it keeps giving me an error that "Cannot place the project in a project Folder that already contains NetBeans project." and this happened a while back then i just deleted the nbproject folder then imported it again and it worked fine. so now i'm out of options, updated the IDE & all the gems, even reinstalled the IDE, cloned the ROR project again with a different name but it still gave me the same error. Guys i realy need someone who might have came across the same problem and managed to fix it. I know this is not entirely related to programming but its the fundamentals that any programmer might have came across someday.

Thanks
D

Comment: Do I understand correctly that you are trying to open an existing Rails project in Netbeans, and it doesn't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Too late but here is the solution:

File -> New project

Choose Ruby on Rails with existing sources and then choose your existing project directory.